# how can write program with java for check statement's SQL database

Tags: java, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any Java libraries out there that validate SQL syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141499/any-java-libraries-out-there-that-validate-sql-syntax)

How can write a program with java to check syntax's SQL statements that it's true or false !,
example : when i write a statement in run time like

```
SELECT * FROM Table table WHERE column =2 , 
SELECT * FROM Product AS p ORDERED BY name ASC,
```

or any other statements of SQL. If the syntax as its the above print Syntax true else print Syntax False.
please Help Dear Programmer .Thanks a lot .

Comment: @ Didar J. Jamal  : please improve the question with more content and formatting. In the current shape it deserved to be closed.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141499/any-java-libraries-out-there-that-validate-sql-syntax).  Short answer, no.  There are as many SQL variants as there are SQL databases.

Comment: Then vote to close as a duplicate instead of posting an answer stating it is.

Comment: thanks dear ,  but its very complex ,tel my  how can write a program to check ONE statement ,, example (SELECT * FROM TABLE tble ) thanks dear friend , please help .