# Check if SQL statements are correctly formed

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

**Problem:** I have a few hundred sql insert statements in a .SQL file which will be run against a oracle DB. I want to check the insert statements are correctly formed , like i want to detect if i missed any comma's etc. simply i want to make sure the statement will run with out any errors. so i am thinking to write a small java application to check the scripts before it is run is it possible ?

**Sample Query:**

```
INSERT INTO suppliers
(supplier_id, supplier_name)
VALUES
(24553, 'IBM');
```

**i want to check this even before running in the DB . Lets assume i dont have access to any DB.**

Comment: The DB should already tell you if it is not correctly formed.

Comment: check [this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141499/any-java-libraries-out-there-that-validate-sql-syntax)

Comment: @andre i want to check this even before running in the DB . Lets assume i dont have access to any DB.

Comment: From my experience making a parser for a language is not trivial, the work load is in the order of a week to weeks. I think you'll have an easier time setting up an DB to test with.

Comment: [Sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4) seems like a good solution here.

Comment: @rdhs - great idea! @Wills - even if you check syntax you're still not guaranteed an error-free script. And even if it's free of syntax errors you could run into problems with permissions or constraints when you run it for real. If all the INSERTs are for a single table then create your own copy and test with it, using Sqlfiddle as rdhs recommended. If you have multiple tables, polish the script as much as you can and take out any `COMMIT` statements. When you run it, spool the output to a file. If you have any errors, `ROLLBACK` immediately, review the spooled output, fix, and try again.

Answer (score 0):

You could try prefacing each SQL statement with 'explain plan for'. If the SQL is invalid the explain will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

The pseudo code can be

```
loop through lines
{
 Take the string between first '(' and ')' position;
 split the string into first array with separator ',' using split function.

 Take the string between second '(' and ')' position;
 split the string into  second array with separator ',' using split function.

 compare the no of size for first and second array.
 if they are not equal 
 print the statement for correction;
}
```

Hope this help you

Answer (score 0):

I've never worked on Oracle before so I'm not sure if there is some sort of DUMMY/Test mode you can enable.

If all you would like to do is check for things like typos then I would replace all table names to dual and run the inserts.
This will not validate column counts of datatypes through...

Comment: If it were up to me, I would have written a script or program to take the raw data from something like a csv file and have it generate the insert statements.
You could then have your code validate each set of data before hand and it should work everytime provided you handled things like quotes/dbl quotes etc correctly.
This is obviously impractical for small sets of data...

Answer (score 0):

If you know java, you could use this regex pattern, it doesn't however pick up the ( or ), I for the life of me can't figure out how to match for a bracket.
This will only work with your example, and your entire insert needs to be in the same line, with only one insert per line.

`Pattern.compile("^\\s*INSERT\\s+INTO\\s+[a-zA-Z]\\w*\\s*.\\s*[a-zA-Z]\\w*\\s*,\\s*[a-zA-Z]\\w*\\s*.\\s*VALUES\\s*.\\s*\\d+\\s*,\\s*'\\w*\\'\\s*.\\s*;\\s*$");`