# Validation of custom SQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have a plugin which uses MySQL for validation of credentials.

A feature request has been around for quite a while for me to allow users to give their own custom validation SQL for things like permissions management and expiry of accounts.

(Obviously this opens up security holes on the server, but configuration is stored in a file owned by root and is an opt-in feature. Basically, if you can read this file, you can also just get the username and password for the MySQL user, so my implementation hopefully shouldn't open too many holes. This is also why this question is here on StackOverflow, not on Security)

I'm thinking of using a simple file format where SQL can be stored. I'd like to perform prevalidation on the SQL statements in this file. Is there a tool available in Java which will validate SQL statements for MySQL without actually running them?

Comment: When you say 'Validate' what do you mean? Validate against what? Which standard? Which database implementation?

Comment: Apologies, MySQL. Editing question.

Comment: @NaftuliTzviKay . . . Don't store user requests as explicit SQL.  Store them as lists of things to do that your application will convert to SQL.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141499/any-java-libraries-out-there-that-validate-sql-syntax. The first few answers should be of help to you (they include MySQL compatible options)